# method throwing Exception not compiling but no issue with RuntimeException

Tags: java, exception

I have written following sample class to experiment with exception. I have two identical methods, one throws RuntimeException whereas one with Exception not compiling.

> Sample code

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String... args){
        System.out.println(3%-2);
        System.out.println(4%-2);

        Test t1 = new Test();
        t1.mtd1(101);
        t1.mtd2(101);

    }

    public int mtd1( int i) throws RuntimeException{
        System.out.println("mtd");

        return i;
    }

    public int mtd2( int i) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("mtd");

        return i;
    }


}
```

> Error

```
C:\Java\B-A>javac Test.java
Test.java:10: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                t1.mtd2(101);
                       ^
1 error
```

Comment: When a method declaration has one or more exceptions defined using throws clause then the method-call must handle all the defined exceptions.So use try-catch to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.  You can either catch the exception inside your `main()` method, or you can have `main()` also throw an exception.

**Option One:**

```
public static void main(String... args){
    System.out.println(3%-2);
    System.out.println(4%-2);

    Test t1 = new Test();
    try {
        t1.mtd1(101);
        t1.mtd2(101);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Option Two:**

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(3%-2);
    System.out.println(4%-2);

    Test t1 = new Test();
    t1.mtd1(101);
    t1.mtd2(101);
}
```

By the way, it is a bit strange to see you catching `RuntimeException` since this exception is *unchecked*.  Normally unchecked exceptions represent things going run at runtime in such a way that is generally not possible to handle them.

Answer (score 1):

All the exception which derives from the class RuntimeException are referred to as unchecked exceptions. And all the other exceptions are checked exceptions. A checked exception must be caught somewhere in your code. If not code will not compile.